# Mac OS X like sheets on iOS SDK

Tags: ios, macos, sdk, cocoa-sheet

Right now I am building an app that would like to present an ViewController. I was wondering of there was any control that would display this like a os x sheet on an iPad. If there is no control available, how would I go about achieving such a thing?

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent interface on iOS is known as a [popover](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html). It's not quite the same, though -- make sure to carefully read the UI guidelines associated with it, as a popover view is not appropriate in all situations where a sheet would have been on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

OSX sheet are modal window.

If you are really need a modal window in ios, then you need to create a custom view, load it as a modal view through modalViewControllers.